# How do I change the style of the default title bar(color,shape and font formatting) in forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I would like to change the style of the title bar and the form in windows forms application using graphics programming.For example the default colour of the form is blue ,I wanna change it to black.Has anyone got any code or tutorials how i can implement that.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest looking at this links

http://www.codeplex.com/wikipage?ProjectName=CustomerBorderForm&title=Painting%20NonClient%20Area

http://www.codeplex.com/wikipage?ProjectName=CustomerBorderForm

Comment: I have tried understanding in many websites including the links you provided. It would be helpful if a complete code is provided instead of parts.

Comment: I believe link only answers are discouraged here for this reason. Might be worth the answerer remembering that for future use.

Answer (score 0):

set form border style to 'None' FormBorderStyle = None

add a Titlebar "Panel" with a Button in the top Left for an Icon, and the Three Control buttons at the top Right and dock it to the top

You can 'borrow" the windows Control Menu but that is outside the scope